# connected components of birational real surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth real algebraic surfaces in $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$. If X and Y are birational over the reals, then is it true that they also have the same number of connected components (with the topology of $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb R)$ as a real manifold)? Is there an example of birational real surfaces in 3-space that are not diffeomorphic?

Comment: What is the simplest example of two birational surfaces? Are they homeomorphic?

Comment: I am assuming your question is again over the reals. I would guess the simplest example is : any plane and the hyperboloid in the projective 3-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now know the answer. This can be found in *Real Algebraic Geometry* by Bochnak, Coste and Roy. Theorem 3.4.12 says that the number of connected components is a birational invariant.